# Module '"*/node_modules/ngx-echarts/ngx-echarts"' has no exported member 'Ngx Echarts Service'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, echarts

My project was running in Angular 6 with all the packages working properly.

But, when I tried to update it to Angular 8, it gives me the following error while `ng serve`

> Module '"*/node_modules/ngx-echarts/ngx-echarts"' has no exported member 'NgxEchartsService'.

I need the solution for the above issue. Currently, I have updated all the dependencies to Angular 8.
The current version on ngx-echarts is `4.2.2`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

upgrade ngx-echarts to ^5.0.0 and change module import to this, i hope help

`import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';`

`import * as echarts from 'echarts';`

`@NgModule({imports: [NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({echarts})]}) export class AppModule {}`